# Trying to return api data and returning undefined values

Tags: reactjs, api

Im trying to render data from the ticket master API. its showing up in the console.log, but when I call it in the card>img>src and title im getting undefined values, and errors.

```
const Cards = (props) => {

  const apiUrl = 'https://app.ticketmaster.com/discovery/v2/events.json?apikey=7elxdku9GGG5k8j0Xm8KWdANDgecHMV0'
  
  
  const [api, setApi] = useState(null)
  const getApi = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(apiUrl);    
    const data = await response.json();
    setApi(data);
    console.log(data._embedded.events[0].name)
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getApi(api);
  }, []);

  

    const numArr = [1,2,3]
    return (
        <div className ='Cards'>
            {
                numArr.map((data, index) => (
                    <div>
                    <Card>
                      <CardImg top width="100%" src={`data._embedded.events[0].images[7]`} alt="Card image cap" />
                      <CardBody>
                        <CardTitle tag="h5"></CardTitle>
                        <CardText>This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</CardText>
                        <CardText>
                          <small className="text-muted">Put some text here</small>
                        </CardText>
                      </CardBody>
                    </Card>
                  </div>
                ))
            }
        </div>
    )  
}
```

Comment: You're mapping through the numArr which is a simple array with [1,2,3]. So when you map it your data will be 1 and then 2 and then 3. So it will not point to your "data" inside your state, try to change the map to numArr.map((_, index) => {...} ) and see what it'll give you

Answer (score 0):

`numArr` in your code is an array of numbers, the Array method `Array.map` receives a callback where the first parameter is one element of the array, and the second its index.

When trying to pass the image src to the `CardImg` Component you pass `data._embedded.events[0].images[7]`.

But `"data"` here is a number, element of `numArr`, so, when running the code, javascript will throw an error saying something like `cannot read property 'events' of undefined` since _embedded is not a property of type number.

It's not quite clear if you're trying to map `event.images` or `_embedded.events` but this is what i think you are trying to do.

```
const Cards = (props) => {

  const apiUrl = 'https://app.ticketmaster.com/discovery/v2/events.json?apikey=7elxdku9GGG5k8j0Xm8KWdANDgecHMV0'


  const [api, setApi] = useState(null)
  const getApi = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(apiUrl);    
      const data = await response.json();
      setApi(data);
      console.log(data._embedded.events[0].name)
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getApi(api);
  }, []);


  return (
    <div className ='Cards'>
        {
            api._embedded.events[0].images.map((src, index) => (
                <div>
                <Card>
                  <CardImg top width="100%" src={src} alt="Card image cap" />
                  <CardBody>
                    <CardTitle tag="h5"></CardTitle>
                    <CardText>This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</CardText>
                    <CardText>
                      <small className="text-muted">Put some text here</small>
                    </CardText>
                  </CardBody>
                </Card>
              </div>
            ))
        }
    </div>
)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your calling data in img tag which is not a global variable
just use api variable since you assign data into it

```
          <CardImg top width="100%" src={api._embedded.events[0].images[7]} alt="Card image cap" />
```